# How to add my IP to cPanel's Remote MySQL Database Host with Delphi?

Tags: mysql, delphi

I coded a program which connects to my web host's MySQL database. I have no problem with it.
But since I do not have a static IP and my IP changes every time I close my modem. I always add my new IP to Cpanel's Remote MySQL Host panel and then I am ready to go and connect to my database.

It is very difficult for me to add my modem ip to Remote MySQL Host manually every time it changes.

Is there a way if I can add my modem IP to Remote MySQL Host panel with Delphi coding?

Comment: Have you done a search for `cpanel api`?

Comment: Nope, I didnt try that. What should i look for with that?

Comment: Do you know what an API is?

Comment: Does the router with which you connect to your internet service provider have a feature called "dynamic DNS?"  If so, you may be able to give your own network a hostname, like DelphiCoding.dyndns.org.  Then you can put that hostname into cpanel.  But, doing that will require you to learn a bit about internet plumbing.

Comment: have you ever heard about no ip ?

Comment: I took the liberty of doing your research for you (although we shouldn't be). I think this is the API call you need: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/WHM+API+1+-+addips

Comment: It's unusual to do this. Normally you would connect to the db from the web host machine. Why connect to the db remotely like this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've done something like this before. Say you have a script (eg, php) and it saves stuff in a MySQL DB. In my case, I wrote a Windows Delphi app that I use to read that data and perform some analyses on it. The script has no API; the DB is a captive data store, and the author never expected anybody else to access the data in the DB. It's a lot easier than writing a proxy script in PHP. Anyway, if the machine gets different IPs due to DHCP, I'd use a dynamic DNS service to resolve it on the host side. That said, you should be able to open up MySQL to not check the IP.

Comment: In my cPanel under Databases, there's an icon for "Remote MySQL". WHen you click it, it shows: "Remote Database Access Hosts -- 
You can allow external web servers [or apps, in this case] to access your MySQL databases by adding their domain name to the list of hosts that are able to access databases on your web site." You can use a fully-qualified domain name, full IP address, or wildcards to specify Class A, B, or C IP ranges.

Comment: I found a solution,from Cpnael if you add ( % ) to the panel it accapts all remote connections